# How can I get multiple results from the same filter with the REST API?

Tags: 9

I am using the Drupal REST API UI module to create filters I can search. I have one for a page type called Category. If I want to search for category 52 I can use *api/resources/?category_id=52*.

I have some scenarios where I need to populate results from different categories. So for example I want all pages with category 52 and 57 to appear. If I try *api/resources/?category_id=52&category_id=57*, it only loads the results from the last filter, which is 57.

Is there a way to show results from more than 1 category?

Comment: Does this work? `api/resources/?category_id[]=52&category_id[]=57`